# Running PHP locally with Ubuntu

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Google Cloud Platform and I'm trying to run a test file called `login.php`. The path is `/var/www/login.php`. Whenever I try running it, I use `sudo php -f /var/www/login.php` then check **http://localhost/var/www/login.php** on my web browser. However, my web browser returns with **This site can’t be reached, localhost refused to connect.** I have looked everywhere for a solution but my web browser always comes back with an error.

Comment: Re-read https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: The instructions aren't very clear, and even I'm doing it right it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `http://localhost` to reach your VM running in GCP.

**To solve your issue** you should follow the documentation [Built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), also you should configure [network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) for your VM instance and create new [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall).

Please have a look on my steps below:

1. create VM instance:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=us-central1-a --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20200610 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud
```

2. [configure](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#adding_new_tags_to_vm_instances) network tag on VM instance:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=us-central1-a --tags=php-http-server
```

3. [create](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall#creating_a_firewall_ingress_rule) firewall rule to allow inbound traffic on port 8080:

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-php-http-8080 --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:8080 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=php-http-server
```

4. install php 7.2:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install php7.2
```

5. create `index.php` file:

```
$ cd /var/www/
$ cat index.php 
<?php
echo 'Hello World!';
?>
```

6. start a PHP web server from the folder with `index.php` file:

```
$ php -S localhost:8080
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 Development Server started at Thu Jun 18 12:31:16 2020
Listening on http://localhost:8080
Document root is /var/www
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

7. check connection from VM instance (via secondary SSH connection):

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080
Hello World!
```

8. start a PHP web server on internal IP of your VM instance:

```
$ php -S 10.128.0.4:8080
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 Development Server started at Thu Jun 18 12:40:46 2020
Listening on http://10.128.0.4:8080
Document root is /var/www
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

9. check connection from on-premises on external IP of your VM:

```
$ curl http://34.XXX.XXX.121:8080
Hello World!
```

same result via web browser at `http://34.XXX.XXX.121:8080`:

> Hello World!

In addition, have a look at [Getting started with PHP on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/getting-started-on-compute-engine) to see an alternative solution.